# Pass commit hash to a git function in a pretty format

Tags: git

My git repo is huge (and created by people knowing only clearcase) and I want to find all the commits refering to an issue Id on all branches and at the same time knowing which branches **contain** the commits.

However, the following attempt won't work as the `$(git branch …)` is expanded before the `%h` is.

```
git log --all --oneline --grep="FOO-1337" --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h $(git branch --contains=%h)"
```

Is there a shorter solution than looping through the output of `git log` as in the following:

```sh
for commit in $(git log --all --oneline --grep="FOO-1337" --pretty=format:"%h");
do
     branches=$(git branch --contains=$commit | tr '\n' ',')
     git show --oneline --quiet --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h ${branches}" $commit; 
done
```

(which I can, of course define as an alias but it seems a bit contrived to me)

Answer (score 1):

How about including the decorate info in the format:

```
git log --all --oneline --grep="FOO-1337" --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h %D"
```

won't that do the trick?

Comment: Nice first answer. Welcome :) Didn't know about the `%D`... seems almost the same as `--decorate` except that you won't be able to filter out tags...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and Welcome! As I commented on @ChrisMaes answer, this is unfortunately not what I wanted. But obviously my question was poorly explained as you both understood the same thing :)

Comment: In this instance, I suspect you won't get around calling git separately per commit id, and therefore a foor loop like you constructed...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you would like your `git log` command to show all branch names? You could just use the `--decorate` option which will show all references (branches, tags, ...) for each commit: something like:

```
git log --all --oneline --decorate ...
```

If you only want the branches to be shown (and not the tags), you could use:

```
--decorate-refs=refs/{remotes,heads}/
```

more information in the [git log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this won't do the trick as `--decorate` only shows the ref pointing to the tags. `git branch --contains=<ref>` gives a list of branch containing the commit which might not be directly pointing to the ref (and thus won't be shown by `decorate`)

Comment: That just completely changed your question... it is a whole different thing listing branchas that "contain" (strange notion in `git` by the way) a commit rather than pointing to a commit. Not sure `git` has an easy solution for that.

Comment: I know it's a strange notion. But as I said, most of the staff knows only clearcase and the migration was done by people knowing only clearcase… Sorry for the imprecision in the OP…